# I am having an issue with an array of integers; it is hard to explain

Tags: c

I'm having trouble with this part of a program where i need to convert from a specific letter to a specific number (basically if a is input, then I want it to return 1). The intArray is capturing the numbers, but it isn't ending after that. it goes on to print out a ton more. there is no specific length that the array of characters has to be, so I just put a somewhat large amount. str1 will be letters that are input.

```
    char str1[200];
    char alphabet[27] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int num[27] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};
    int intArr1[200];

    w = 0;
    for(i=0;i<27;i++)
    {
        if(str1[w] == alphabet[i])
        {
            intArr1[w] = num[i];
            w++;
            i = 0;
        }
        else if(str1[w] == '\0')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    int len = sizeof(intArr1);
    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        printf("%d", intArr1[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `sizeof(intArr1)` returns the size of the declared array (in bytes, mind you...), not the amount of elements in the array. It will always print everything in that array, even if it's "garbage"

Comment: When you populate `intArr1` with a value, you need to increment a counter. When you are done populating `intArr1`, the counter you incremented will equal the populated size of `intArr1`. Or in other words, it will equal the useful length of `intArr1`.

Comment: @StarPilot that would be `w` in his code.

Comment: Tyvm both of you. That works perfectly StarPilot :) I actually already had w there that is already incremented haha. i just didn't think of it before

Comment: But it isn't used consistently for that. His outer scan loop wants to go through each letter of the alphabet, but his code wants to use `w` as the index counter for his scan through `str1`. If he walks the whole array of `str1`, then `w` will not hold the actual populated count of `intArr1`. His code is currently `slightly confused` as currently posted.

Comment: yeah i didn't post the whole thing, but w works for it. I put in an exception to catch if they input anything besides alphabet anyways.

Comment: I removed my comment about uninitialized compare concerning `if(str1[w] == alphabet[i])` as OP's post _describes_ that `str1` is an input array.  Code speaks louder than words.  Using `void foo(char *str1, int size)` would have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple issues:

```
int len = sizeof(intArr1);  // this line returns the number of 
                            // bytes the array occupies (800 in your case)
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    printf("%d", intArr1[i]);
}
```

The `sizeof` operation will not be appropriate for your usage.

Second, you are keeping a counter to hold the useful length of your `intArr` as you populate it, called `w`. You should use this instead of your computed `len` variable.

```
for(i=0;i<w;i++)
{
    printf("%d", intArr1[i]);
}
```

This should print the useful contents of the array, ending when you think it should.

As pointed out in the comments however, based on your overall goal, you will not want to rely solely on the use of `w` to maintain count, but instead keep an overall global counter that tracks the size of the `intArr`, so you can keep a valid index pointer for multiple passes of your input data.

Good luck...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after StarPilot pointed out using an increment in the comment. TYVM.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using two arrays to compare and print the equivalent number to each character you just need to convert them by shifting there ASCII code (subtracting the character 'a' ASCII code from the character to be converted then adding 1)

Theory:

```
'a' == 97
'a' - 'a' + 1 == 1
'b' - 'a' + 1 == 2
...
'z' - 'a' + 1 == 26
```

Code:

```
void print_array(char *input)
{
    int i = 0;

    while (input[i] != '\0')
    {
        printf("%d", input[i] - 'a' + 1);

        i++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char input[256];

    printf("input : ");
    scanf("%s", input);

    print_array(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP's code, though faulty, does _not_ depend on ASCII encoding.  Your answer relies on ASCII.  Not a bad idea as ASCII is so prevalent, but not a great idea either.

Answer (score 1):

```
the following code is one possibility

// ??? what to do when input char not a...z ???

#define MAX_SIZE (200)

int i=0; // input index
int j=0; // output index

char str1[MAX_SIZE]; // the input characters, null terminated

int intArr1[MAX_SIZE] = {']0'}; // clear the destination array

for(; i < strlen(str1); i++ )
{
    if( 'a' <= str1[i] && 'z' >= str1[i] )
    { // then, convert char to number
        intArr1[j] = str1[i] - 'a' + 1; // +1 so 'a' results in 1

        // update destination index
        j++;
    } // end if
} // end for

// when here, 'j' contains number of characters in destination

for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
{
    printf("%d", intArr1[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why use `int intArr1[MAX_SIZE] = {']0'};`, instead of `int intArr1[MAX_SIZE] = {0};`

Comment: `for(; i < strlen(str1); i++ )` will call `strlen(str1)` each time through the loop.  As `str1` does not change in the loop, suggest pre-calculating the length once.

Comment: `printf("%d", intArr1[i]);` looks better spacing between numbers:  `printf(" %d", intArr1[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
sizeof(intArr1)
```

doesnt give you an array length. It gives the number of bytes the array occupies. If you want the length of the array you should use `sizeof(intArr1)/sizeof(intArr1[0])` -- than gives you the number of elements in your array.

Comment: All i needed to do was use w instead of sizeof(intarr1) anyways. Ty for your answer and sorry for using your time on this :)